# Cosmos DB & Mongo DB interoperability

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

If we have an existing application that uses MongoDB C# driver and we start with it on CosmosDB and let's say we use it for some time and after a while, if we want to move over from MongoDB API and use DocumentDB API, can we use it directly against our database created through MongoDB C# driver?

In other words, does MongoDB API creates regular, 'native' DocumentDB collections in Cosmos DB or are they different in any way?

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not interoperable yet. SQL API and Gremlin API are, however.